# Prove that a 3D packing problem is NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, decision-problem

How can I prove that the following problem is NP-complete?

I have a spherical container in which I have to introduce $n$ identical spheres. All of the little spheres have to be inside the container and they can't overlap each other. The idea is to minimize the container's ratio.

I know that this is a packing problem but it is three-dimensional so I don't know how to prove that it's an NP-complete problem. Can you help me?

The problem appears in Hifi and Yousef, [A hybrid algorithm for packing identical spheres into a container](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417417308084). From the introduction:

> In this paper, the Identical Sphere Packing (denoted ISP) is tackled with a hybrid algorithm that combines the particle swarm optimization and an efficient continuous local optimization. Two types of ISP are considered: the ISP with an *Open container* (denoted O-ISP), where the container has an unlimited length, and the ISP with a *spherical container* (denoted S-ISP), where its radius is unlimited.
>
> An instance of each of both problems is characterized by a set $N$ of $n$ identical spheres, where each sphere $i \in N = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ is represented by its radius $r_i=1$ and the container is either $\mathscr{P}$ with fixed width $W$ and height $H$ but unlimited length $L_0 = \infty$ or $\mathscr{S}$ of unlimited radius $S = \infty$. For both versions of the problem, the goal is to minimize the length $L_0$ (if the container $\mathscr{P}$ is open) or the radius $R_0$ (if the container $\mathscr{S}$ is spherical) such that all items of $N$ are positioned in $\mathscr{P}$ or $R_0$, without overlapping between spheres and between spheres and the container.

I am interested in the second problem, S-ISP.

Comment: What's the input and and what's the output of your problem exactly? (Keep in mind that it must be a decision problem). What's the container's ratio?

Comment: The input is the number of spheres and the output is the ratio of the container

Comment: So the input is just a single number $n$? What is the ratio of the container? The output must be yes or no for the problem to even belong to NP.

Comment: Did you check whether any of the references listed in Section 2 show hardness? I think Wascher, Haussner & Schumann 2007 would be good start.

Comment: The input is $n$ and a radius $S$, and the question is whether you can fit $n$ many radius-1 spheres in a sphere of radius $S$, all in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Please credit your source.

Comment: Also, please transcribe the text to make it accessible to screen readers and search engines.

Comment: Since the input is just 2 numbers, the *size of* the input is just $O(\log(n+S))$, meaning an algorithm that takes time polynomial in $n$ or $S$ is already exponential in the input size. This should make it more likely to be NP-hard -- but OTOH I have no clue how to reduce any existing NP-hard problem to this problem (or to any problem who input just contains a constant number of integers).

Comment: Isn't that stated somewhere in the paper???